# What are the command extensions for CMD's COLOR command?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

The help for `CMD.exe` lists the `COLOR` command as being affected by the `ENABLEEXTENSIONS` arguments. It further states to see what those extensions are you need to look at the command's local help.

`COLOR /?` makes no mention of the extensions.

What are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EnableExtensions` determines whether the extensions to the command processor (`cmd.exe`), such as `chdir`, `setlocal`, and `color`, are enabled. Because the extensions might be incompatible with a command-script language, Windows 2000+ lets you disable the extensions. This entry affects all extensions. You cannot use this entry to selectively enable or disable extensions. You can, however, disable extensions for a particular invocation of `cmd.exe` by using the `/E:OFF` switch.

Globally located at `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\EnableExtensions`.

```
C:\Users\jnovack>cmd /E:ON
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\jnovack>color 1f
(color changes to bold white (f) on blue (1))
C:\Users\jnovack>color
(color reverts to normal)

C:\Users\jnovack>cmd /E:OFF
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\jnovack>color fc
'color' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

---

`COLOR [attr]`

`attr`        Specifies color attribute of console output

Color attributes are specified by TWO hex digits -- the first
corresponds to the background; the second the foreground.  Each digit
can be any of the following values:

```
0 = Black       8 = Gray
1 = Blue        9 = Light Blue
2 = Green       A = Light Green
3 = Aqua        B = Light Aqua
4 = Red         C = Light Red
5 = Purple      D = Light Purple
6 = Yellow      E = Light Yellow
7 = White       F = Bright White
```

Reference:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959665.aspx
- http://www.dostips.com/DosCommandIndex.php#COLOR

Comment: The body of your answer provides backgorund as to enabling or disabling the extensions and not how it affected the COLOR command. It was the example with it off that showed the COLOR command is only available with the extensions on. I edited the answer to put that up front.

Comment: Too bad you've rejected @RichShealer's edit! I've had "drive-by" interest to this problem and had a trouble getting simple answer from the waffle as well. It isn't factually correct even due mention of `chdir` (was `cd` alias **always**). To recap:

Comment: **COLOR internal command IS actually a Command Extension itself**

Comment: @FreeConsulting Good comprehension!  That's literally what the first line says.  "extensions to the command processor...such as ... color".  Heavily implies that color, is an extension to the command processor.

Comment: Unfortunately, it stops being perceived literally just before that because of chdir.

Comment: Useful answer, but I agree with earlier comments that the text could be clarified. The `color` command is now mentioned in one sentence together with `chdir` and other commands, while `chdir` is always available (but modified with extensions enabled), while the `color` command is **added** by enabling the extensions.